# Dockerfile entrypoint not lunching on interactive mode

Tags: docker

I'm absolutely new to Docker. I want a docker to do `git pull` / `git push` / resolve conflicts on some repositories.

I've created this Dockerfile

```
FROM needcaffeine/git

RUN apt-get update

RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh
ADD .ssh/id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 700 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN echo "Host github.com\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" >> /root/.ssh/config

VOLUME ["/root/repos"]

ENTRYPOINT ["bash"]
```

but when I run it with

```
docker run my-tag-for-that-image
```

It don't give me an interactive prompt even when I'm using `bash` as `ENTRYPOINT`.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `-it` to `docker run`, i.e.:

```
docker run my-tag-for-that-image
```

From `docker help run`:

```
  -i, --interactive=false     Keep STDIN open even if not attached
  -t, --tty=false             Allocate a pseudo-TTY
```